# IntelliJ Idea lost suddenly JBOSS management port configuration

Tags: java, intellij-idea, configuration, jboss, wildfly-8

I didn't touch any configuration file or IntelliJ IDEA setting but I just suddenly lost the HTTP management port configuration in my JBOSS WildFly 8.1 configuration.

How could this have happened and where to look for a fix? I sure as heck didn't touch standalone.xml.

[image]

**EDIT:** Hmm ok strange, now I went to check my standalone.xml and instead of that the configuration directory had only standalone.xml.tmp.

No slightest idea why this happened. First time ever. But renaming it back to standalone.xml fixed the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

standalone.xml had turned into standalone.xml.tmp for an unknown reason. I hadn't edited the file or had it open anywhere.

Renaming the file back to standalone.xml fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this issue once my IDEA updated this morning. Just replace your existing `standalone.xml` with original one which is from `jboss.zip`. If you have custom config in `standalone.xml`, set up profile in maven for wildfly plugin instead of manually modify this xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I randomly got this issue yesterday on 2020.3 so I thought I'd share another possible solution.

I checked my standalone.xml and everything looked normal. For me, the only way to fix this was to remove and re-add the artifact in the Run Configuration. It's a simple solution, but hopefully this will help someone who's getting this issue on a recent version of IntelliJ.